# How to detect Panelizer use in template_preprocess_html()?

Tags: 8, theming, panels

In Drupal 7, you could look for `$node->panelizer` or use `page_manager_get_current_page()` to check if the current page uses a panelizer layout. How do you do that in Drupal 8?

I'm trying to add a body class if the current page contains a specific pane.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out you do have access to $node->panelizer. So here's what I did:

```
function MYMODULE_preprocess_html(&$vars) {
  $node = \Drupal::routeMatch()->getParameter('node');
  if ($node instanceof \Drupal\node\NodeInterface) {
    if (isset($node->panelizer)) {
      $panelizer = $node->panelizer->getValue();
      // do whatever checks are needed
      // and use $vars['attributes']->addClass('MYCLASS') when ready
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if this is quite what you're after, but these hooks will fire if your page is using panelizer.

```
/**
 * Implements hook_preprocess_panels_pane().
 */
function YOURTHEME_preprocess_panels_pane(&$$variables) {
  // If this triggers then you are in a panels pane.
}
```

OR

```
/**
 * Implements hook_panels_pane_content_alter().
 */
 function YOUR_MODULE_panels_pane_content_alter($content, $pane, $args, $contexts) {
  // If this triggers then you are altering panels content.
}
```

If you want to check for panelizer in the node you could try something like this:

```
$node = \Drupal::routeMatch()->getParameter('node');
if ($node->hasField('panelizer')) {
  // Do stuff
}
```